# Why am I getting the "redefinition of link as different kind of symbol" error?

Tags: c, linked-list, typedef

I'm defining link as a `struct STnode` pointer, but I get an error. The error occurs in this header file, and this is the only place where `link` is defined. Here's the entire headeer file

```
 // Top-down red-black tree header file
 // These will have to change if data in node is more than just an int.
 typedef int Key;
 typedef Key Item;
 #define key(A) (A)
 #define less(A, B) (key(A) < key(B))
 #define eq(A, B) (key(A) == key(B))

 typedef struct STnode* link;

 struct STnode
 {
     Item item;  // Data for this node
     link l, r;  // left & right links
     char red;   // RB color
     int N;      // subtree size
 };

 extern Item NULLitem;

 void STinit();          // Initialize tree with just a sentinel

 Item STsearch(Key v);   // Find node for a key

 Item STselect(int k);   // Treat tree as flattened into an ordered array

 int STinvSelect(Key v); // Inverse of STselect

 void extendedTraceOn(); // Full tracing of intermediate trees

 void basicTraceOn();    // Just trace down and up passes for insert

 void traceOff();        // Run silent

 void STinsert(Item item);     // Insert an item.  No uniqueness check

 void verifyRBproperties();    // Ensure that tree isn't damaged

 void STprintTree();           // Dumps out tree

 void cleanUpUnbalanced(link h);  // Includes subtree sizes and verifies a               
 tree
 // built without balancing
```

Whenever I look up where `link` is initially defined, it directs me to a header file that I don't even use in this code. Thanks for all the help in advance.

EDIT: Code post-changing every `link` to `STlink`.

```
 // Top-down red-black tree header file
 // These will have to change if data in node is more than just an int.
 typedef int Key;
 typedef Key Item;
 #define key(A) (A)
 #define less(A, B) (key(A) < key(B))
 #define eq(A, B) (key(A) == key(B))

 typedef struct STnode* STlink; // Source

 struct STnode  // Error received - "redefinition of 'STnode' which directs me
                   to source above.
 {
     Item item;  // Data for this node
     STlink l, r;  // left & right links
     char red;   // RB color
     int N;      // subtree size
 };

 extern Item NULLitem;

 void STinit();          // Initialize tree with just a sentinel

 Item STsearch(Key v);   // Find node for a key

 Item STselect(int k);   // Treat tree as flattened into an ordered array

 int STinvSelect(Key v); // Inverse of STselect

 void extendedTraceOn(); // Full tracing of intermediate trees

 void basicTraceOn();    // Just trace down and up passes for insert

 void traceOff();        // Run silent

 void STinsert(Item item);     // Insert an item.  No uniqueness check

 void verifyRBproperties();    // Ensure that tree isn't damaged

 void STprintTree();           // Dumps out tree

 void cleanUpUnbalanced(STlink h);  // Includes subtree sizes and verifies a               
 tree
 // built without balancing
```

Comment: Try `man 2 link` which will shed some light on it. It is a predefined command for creating hard-links.

Comment: Which is that header file that you "don't even use" ? Maybe this header file is included by one of the header files you include.

Comment: @MichaelWalz unlstd.h, which is really weird since the defined `link` in there is `int link(const char *, const char *);`.

Comment: @Kenshin I think you found the answer, And unistd.h is included by one or more of the system include files you include. Just rename you `link` symbol and you're out of trouble.

Comment: @MichaelWalz renamed every `link` symbol to `STlink` as @R Sahu suggested, but now I get the same error at `struct STnode`, with the original definition point back to now `typedef struct STnode* STlink;`. Any ideas on why that is happening? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Every `link` symbol, including `link l, r;`? Post the new error, it cannot be the same as the original if you removed all references to `link`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I edited in the new header file along w/ the error I receive.

Comment: Are the comments that wrap in your post just do to posting here? e.g. `to source above.` is really connected to the previous line in your code? We all want to help, but can't unless you post the exact error message you are getting. If you had posted the full code, then  I would compile it here to verify, but I can't with the limited parts you posted. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The error occurs in this header file, and this is the only place where `link` is defined.

Not sure where the first `link` is defined but you can resolve this issue by using `STlink` instead of `link` in your portion of the code.